# SwiftUI previews don't work with custom library

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, swiftui-previews

I have a project where we integrate with a wearable by integrating a static library (a `.a` file). Ever since I integrated this library, SwiftUI Previews no longer works. The error I get is:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_BleSdk_1963YH
```

Which is located in the library.

This library is only built for devices (`lipo -info framework.a` returns `armv7 arm64`), so I understand that the SwiftUI preview (which runs on my computer) can't build the app, but it has been really annoying not being able to use SwiftUI Previews.

This has been a difficult way to develop new views (or change existing views). Currently I have another project where I develop my layout (where SwiftUI Previews work), then I copy the view code over and I integrate it with the rest of the app.

I think there must be a better way to do this, but I don't know how. Can someone help me?

Comment: You would typically create a mock object model and inject that into your previews

Comment: No it's not that I cannot use the device in previews, it's that the preview is not shown due to the app not being buildable for simulator (because of the integrated library)

Comment: Put your views into their own framework and the you can include that framework in both your test app and the real app.

Comment: That's just what I am doing, but with more steps. I want to know how I can make this app build on simulator (so the previews work like they should)

Comment: That is why I suggested you make the views in their own package. That way you don't need to keep copying the code.  You can add that as a development package to both targets